# Using Html Agility Pack for parsing Html

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I have this html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<div style="background: #5b7fa6; padding: 2px 3px 3px 3px; border-bottom: 1px solid #6f91bb;">
<b style="color: #FFFFFF;">Gain Access to VK</b>
</div>
<div style="border-top: 1px solid #4a6a91; padding:10px;">
<div style="background: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #adbbca; padding: 5px;'">
<form method="POST" action="https://login.vk.com/?act=login&amp;soft=1&amp;utf8=1">
</form>
</div>  
</div>
</body></html>
```

I want to get value of action attribute in form element.
I using this code

```
    HtmlNode formNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("html/body/div[2]/div/form");
    if (formNode != null)
    {
        var action = formNode.GetAttributeValue("action", string.Empty);
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(action))
        {
            //to do 
        }
    }
```

But formNode is null. I think that the problem in 'DOCTYPE'.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `form` tag occurs only once why not try something like this

```
HtmlNode formNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form");
```

Comment: Sorry. Error was not in this expression. Error was here streamReader.ReadToEnd(); and then `HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();`
        `htmlDoc.Load(sr);` But method ReadToEnd set property `EndOfStream` to true and were loaded incorrect data.